# how to search for a given sequence of rows within a table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sequence

The problem:

We have a number of entries within a table but we are only interested in the ones that appear in a given sequence. For example we are looking for three specific "GFTitle" entries ('Pearson Grafton','Woolworths (P and O)','QRX - Brisbane'), however they have to appear in a particular order to be considered a valid route. (See image below)

```
RowNum  GFTitle
------------------------------
   1    Pearson Grafton
   2    Woolworths (P and O)
   3    QRX - Brisbane
   4    Pearson Grafton
   5    Woolworths (P and O)
   6    Pearson Grafton
   7    QRX - Brisbane
   8    Pearson Grafton
   9    Pearson Grafton
```

So rows (1,2,3) satisfy this rule but rows (4,5,6) don't even though the first two entries (4,5) do.

I am sure there is a way to do this via CTE's but some help would be great.

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, please highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `RowNum` has neither duplicates nor gaps, you could try the following method.

1. Assign row numbers to the sought sequence's items and join the row set to your table on `GFTitle`.
2. For every match, calculate the difference between your table's row number and that of the sequence. If there's a matching sequence in your table, the corresponding rows' `RowNum` differences will be identical.
3. Count the rows per difference and return only those where the count matches the number of sequence items.

Here's a query that implements the above logic:

```
WITH SoughtSequence AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    VALUES
      (1, 'Pearson Grafton'),
      (2, 'Woolworths (P and O)'),
      (3, 'QRX - Brisbane')
  ) x (RowNum, GFTitle)
)
, joined AS (
  SELECT
    t.*,
    SequenceLength = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.RowNum - ss.RowNum)
  FROM atable t
  INNER JOIN SoughtSequence ss
  ON t.GFTitle = ss.GFTitle
)
SELECT
  RowNum,
  GFTitle
FROM joined
WHERE SequenceLength = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SoughtSequence)
;
```

You can try it [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d36c5/1) too.

Comment: Thank you Andriry M. It is the exact solution I was looking for. I need to work more with CTE's as I believe them to be very powerful tools. I just find it hard to fully understand how they operate.

Comment: It helped me to understand CTEs better when I started thinking of them as views with limited visibility scope (views only available to the statement in whose context they are defined).

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple using even good old tools :-) Try this quick-and-dirty solution, assuming your table name is `GFTitles` and `RowNumber` values are sequential:

```t-sql
SELECT a.[RowNum]
      ,a.[GFTitle]
      ,b.[GFTitle]
      ,c.[GFTitle]
 FROM [dbo].[GFTitles] as a
      join [dbo].[GFTitles] as b on b.RowNumber = a.RowNumber + 1
      join [dbo].[GFTitles] as c on c.RowNumber = a.RowNumber + 2
WHERE a.[GFTitle] = 'Pearson Grafton' and
      b.[GFTitle] = 'Woolworths (P and O)' and
      c.[GFTitle] = 'QRX - Brisbane'
```

Comment: Thank you Serg. This solution works well if there are always only three GFTitles but this solution has to be able to be, as Andriy M put it Scalable and this is where I run into trouble.

Comment: Not a problem to make it scalable - use dynamic SQL and form SQL command as long as you need :-) However, of course, it's not full-featured solution and was offered as quick response to your question.